# Access Sony cameras with the Camera Remote API beta

Tags: android, sony-camera-api

Does the Sony Camera Remote API work via cable also or is it WiFi only?

Answer (score 0):

Sony Camera Remote API does not work via USB, only via WiFi. It's HTTP-based and requires an IP connection with the camera, which can be established only using the camera's access point.